# UITouch point different when placing in UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am taking the `CGTouch` of a `View` as shown in the code below and trying to place a dot on a UIImage, which does't have the same size in pixels as the view is in points.

So I have to scale the image that it displays the `dot` on the correct point.

Anyhow, when I tried to place the `newPoint` after doing some convertions the dot is placed at a different location than was shown in the UITouch point of the View. How can I solve this ?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    let touch = touches.first

    if let point = touch?.location(in: self.view) {


        print(point.x)
        print(point.y)

        // Scaling the image to it places the dot proportionate to the UITouch points of the View

        let X = CGFloat(point.x / self.view.frame.size.width)
        let y = CGFloat(point.y / self.view.frame.size.height)

        let newPoint = CGPoint(x: image.size.width * X , y: image.size.height * y )



    }
}
```

UPDATE

[image]

According to the first image. I click on a point on the screen (The yellow dot). Now, I save the image that i see on the screen to a UIImage.

For some reason, the dimentions of the UIImage wasn't the same as what I saw on the device before (as shown in image 2). So now, If I go and place the touch point (that was obtained in screen 1) and place it on screen 2, it appears in a different area on the image.

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear. Can you add a picture that illustrates what you want to do? Your coordinate computations look strange. `point` is relative to `self.view`. So you should use `self.view.bounds` instead of `self.view.frame`. What is the coordinate system from `newPoint`? If it is `view` too, you should add the image offsets. The size of the image may also differ from the size of its view.

Comment: @macmoonshine I have updated my post with an image